# can you help me solve this collection.get() function error?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I was trying to use a database in my project, so i imported 'collection' to use it
this is my code:

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-app.js";
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signOut, signInWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-auth.js";
import { getFirestore, collection } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-firestore.js";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyC3GLIN5TBmCDoTfy0dEOgOdvVvqNw-ric",
  authDomain: "auth-project-38aaa.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "auth-project-38aaa",
  storageBucket: "auth-project-38aaa.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "431888894254",
  appId: "1:431888894254:web:71bb9b250fbb8a21edd2bf",
  measurementId: "G-6BBPCJ3814"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);

// get data
collection(db, 'guides').get().then(snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot.docs);
});
```

but instead of showing me the 'snapshot.docs' in the console it gives me this message:

```
auth.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: collection(...).get is not a function
    at auth.js:20
```

please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're importing the new modular/functional SDK, where the equivalent of `collectionRef.get()` is actually:

```
getDocs(collection(db, 'guides')).then(snapshot => {
  ...
```

---

The Firebase documentation itself has all been updated to contain both the older snippets, and snippets for the new API, such as in this case the documentation on [getting multiple documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#web-version-9_6).

But if you're new to Firebase and using code from other places, those might not have both snippets styles yet. In that case it might be easier to start by [importing the `compat` libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_v9_compat) from the new SDKs, while you're figuring out how everything works. If you just want to do that for Firestore, it'd be:

```
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```